# Mongoid query too slow in rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am using rails 4 with mongoid (4.0.0 alpha1). Problem is that when i try to fetch records in controller using

```
Model.where(:status => 'Active')
```

It takes too long (about 10seconds). Same is the issue when i try to query records in console. Collection has almost 400+ records.

But fetching records in mongodb console

```
db.collection.find({status: "Active"})
```

is quick.

Is  there any issue in mongoid 4.0.0.alpha1 ? Any suggestion how to improve query response time in rails?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was mainly due to large size embedded documents. Fixed issue by loading only required fields like

```
Model.only(:name,:created_at)
```

or

```
Model.without(:heavy_embedded_document_name)
```

Also we modify our database structure to decrease size of embedded documents and objects it self.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure `status` has an index. You can create an index in the [MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-an-index/) console:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex( { status: 1 } )
```

Or in [Mongoid](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/indexing.html):

```
class Person
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :status

  index({ status: 1 })
end
```

Comment: Yes i have added index on status field but it does't enhance query performance alot. Query is still running slowly.

Comment: Main issue is that our collection contains data in embedded documents due to which some collection objects have size of about 600kb 700kb. We have make a work arond for that by fetching records without embedded document i.e.

'Model.without(:embedded_documents).where(:status => "Active")'

It enhanced query execution time (now records are fetched within 100ms in most cases). But new problem is that, how to fetch embedded document when we need it? If we again fetch record with embedded document then same problem comes again.